# Reset horizontal sliding div position when next sliding div is triggered

Tags: jquery, slider, position, reset

I've got a page that is really long. I want to break it into 4 mini pages(divs), then use text navigation to slide from one page div to the next. There is also a close button that hides all the divs and reveals the original page below.

The problem I'm having is that when the user clicks the link to the next div, the previous div doesn't reset itself as if it were never clicked. The first time you click on say "Page 2", the Page 2 div slides in from the left, no problem. But if you click on it again later, the div just appears with no sliding animation.

I thought using removeAttr("style"); would do exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem to work in this instance.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(".page-link").bind("click", function() {
    $(".ntc-pages").fadeOut(1000);
   //   THIS DOESN'T WORK
   // $(this).removeAttr('style');

var divId= $(this).attr("divId");
$("#" + divId).animate({
opacity: 1,
left: "0",
height: "toggle"},
 500, function() {
  });
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg1">
    <h4>PAGE 1</h4>
</a>

<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg2">
    <h4>PAGE 2</h4>
</a>

<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg3">   
    <h4>PAGE 3</h4>
</a>

<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg4">
    <h4>PAGE 4</h4>
</a>


<div class="ntc-pages" id="pg1">PAGE 1<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg2"> PAGE 2</a> 
<a class="back-ntc" href="javascript:void(0);">Back</a>
</div>

<div class="ntc-pages" id="pg2">PAGE 2<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg3"> PAGE 3</a> 
<a class="back-ntc" href="javascript:void(0);">Back</a>
</div>

<div class="ntc-pages" id="pg3">PAGE 3<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg4"> PAGE 4</a> 
<a class="back-ntc" href="javascript:void(0);">Back</a>
</div>

<div class="ntc-pages" id="pg4">PAGE 4<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" divId="pg1"> PAGE 1</a> 
<a class="back-ntc" href="javascript:void(0);">Back</a>
</div>
```

And a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwjLuff1/) of how it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you never return the animated div back to it's original position (-1200px to the left), so when you go to animate it the next time, it is already there (0px to the left), which is why the sliding doesn't appear to work.

A couple other things to note:

- Instead of using `divID`, it would be more correct to use something like a data attribute, such as `data-page="1"` and reference by `$("#someID").data("page")`
- Instead of using `href="javascript:void(0);"` on your anchors, in your JS code you could instead pass in the event object such as `$(".page-link").click(function(e) {...});` and make use of `e.preventDefault();` to stop the links from executing
- Instead of binding the click function, simply use jQuery click as I did in the last point
- If you want to change the styles of an object with JS, you could do so using `$(".myClass").css("left", "-1200px");`

So, to quickly fix your problem, you could add `$(".ntc-pages").css("left", "-1200px");` to the top of the bind function callback, however I would suggest going through and adding some of the above suggestions as well.

Here's a jsfiddle with the above line added: https://jsfiddle.net/ens28yxp/

Comment: I suspected that. Any suggestions on how to return the previous div to -1200 without causing the currently showing div to also go to -1200?

Comment: Please see my edits and let me know if you have any questions. I made a couple of suggestions with regards to your code as well in order to improve it a little bit going forward. It should make things a little easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This works ok, but the problem now is that the previous div immediately hides, which shows a flash of the page below it. The fadeOut() fixed that before, but now I suspect the div is returning to -1200 before it's fading out. Anyway to delay that?

Comment: There are a couple of things you could try. First being a callback on the fade function so that the css change only gets called after fade has completed. Another option would be to add a delay equal to the time taken for the fade to complete (1s in this case). Basically, what is happening here is the css change is being completed before the entire fade has executed since it takes a full second.

Comment: YES!! Adding a callback on the fade did the trick! $('.ntc-pages').fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).css("left", "-1200px");});

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working! Let me know if you have any other questions.